# Type erasure and inheritance: An object of List<Number> , when accessed from a sub-class is seen as a raw List?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

### Question:

An object of a parametrized class, when accessed from a sub-class is seen as a non-generic. How do I overcome this?

### Details:

Consider a base class:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    protected List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();

    public MyBaseClass(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, let's extend this class:

```
public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {

    public void addSomething() {
        numbers.add(25.0f); //Warning about type-safety here
    }
}
```

In the derived class, the numbers object is seen as a raw type. The warning is:

> Type safety: The method add(Object) belongs to the raw type List. References to generic type List should be parameterized.

If I try to add the type parameter myself, I get a compile error:

```
        numbers.<Number>add(25.0f); //Error here
```

The error I see is:

> The method add(Number) of type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

However, if I place both the classes in the same Java source file, then this problem goes away. There is no warning in the first place. This was a sample to illustrate the problem.

In my real application, I want to be able to get elements from the `List` in the derived class, and perform class-specific operations on them without having to first cast the retrieved object to the appropriate type.

I suspect the problem is because of type erasure, but I cannot figure out how to work around it.

---

### EDIT:

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 and Oracle JDK 1.6.0_30 on Fedora Core 16. The compiler compliance is set to 1.6 with default compliance settings. As I mentioned, if I place both classes in the same .java file, then I don't see the warning. It is seen only if I place them in different files.

I can work around this by defining all methods that directly operate on the list object in the parent class; and using this from the derived class.

But I'm still curious as to why I see the warning. Here's the work-around:

In MyBaseClass:

```
    protected void addNumberToList(Number num){
        numbers.add(num);
    }
```

and then in derived class:

```
    public void addSomething() {
        addNumberToList(25.0f);
    }
```

Similarly, all operations that manipulate the `List` object directly can be in the base class.

Comment: Which compiler, mine doesn't behave like that?

Comment: Same here I tried it  and for me no warning.

Comment: I'm puzzled, the above code compiles without errors or warning on my machine, as it should. I'm using JDK 7 Update 4. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: This is really puzzling! I edited the question to add details about the compiler, compliance settings and other environment details.

Answer (score 3):

Your *real* base class is generic, but your subclass inherits from its raw type:

```
public class MyBaseClass<X> {
    protected List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();

    public List<Number> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {
    public void addSomething() {
        numbers.add(25.0f);
    }
}
```

[JLS §4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-400) says the member access will be treated as for raw types. That means `numbers` is treated as raw, hence the warning. The solution is to parameterize the supertypes:

```
public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass<TypeArgumentsHere>
```

Comment: Great answer. +1 for the reference to JLS Section 4.8. You pointed to the specs for SE7; I looked into the [same for SE5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.8) and its the same there. However, I don't see the warning if I place both the classes in the same file. Also, other answers and comments here on this question state that they don't see the warning. How would you explain that?

Comment: @curioustechizen The code you posted in your question is fine. It is type sound and warning-free. I suppose that most posters tried it and didn't see any warnings. If they were to try the code I posted, they would or at least should.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. I am seeing the warnings with the code posted by **me** in the original question. This is what other posters have tried and reported to be working fine without warnings (as it should be according to your explanation).

Comment: @curioustechizen All I can tell you is that -- assuming a correct compiler and no byte code manipulation -- the only way to get that warning is if the supertype to which `numbers` belongs is raw.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse and your code complied well with no warnings or errors. But I think you should provide `protected/public` method instead of exposing the instance variable.

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    protected List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();

    public List<Number> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {

    public void addSomething() {
        getNumbers().add(25.0f);
    }
}
```